# How to check If ng-show is true then do something in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class ="container" ng-show="mbrscemployee=='yes'">
    <span class="btn">click<span>
</div>
<button class="submit">submit</button>
```

When someone press `button` tag, it will check if `ng-show` is `true`, then the `span` will be clicked automatically.

Comment: Despite your unclear English, please try to make yourself more clearer. It's hard to understand what you mean / trying to accomplish?

Comment: What happens when you click the button? It should have an ng-click attribute as well. Also, if you need to check `mbrscemployee=='yes'` multiple times it is worth creating a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the click event to be triggered on the `span` element, after  you click the `button`, when `ng-show` is true:

DOM:

```
<div class="container" ng-show="mbrscemployee=='yes'">
    <span id="myspan" class="btn">click<span>
</div>
<button ng-click="btnClick()" class="submit">submit</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.btnClick = function() {
    if ($scope.mbrscemployee == 'yes') {
        angular.element('#myspan').triggerHandler('click');
    }
}
```

Edit: Although, the following approach makes more sense:

DOM

```
<div class="container" ng-show="mbrscemployee=='yes'">
    <span ng-click="spanClick()" id="myspan" class="btn">click<span>
</div>
<button ng-click="btnClick()" class="submit">submit</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.spanClick = function() {
    // do something
}

$scope.btnClick = function() {
    if ($scope.mbrscemployee == 'yes') {
        $scope.spanClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not add ngClick to the span directly? This is mixing angular and jQuery methodologies

Comment: I agree with you 100%. However, that's how I interpret @ahmdabos's question: "_[...] then the span will be clicked automatically_"

Comment: You can invoke the ngClick function from inside btnClick after running the check

Answer (score 1):

Just check the condition that the `ngShow` uses:

```
<div class ="container" ng-show="mbrscemployee=='yes'">
    <span class="btn">click<span>
</div>
<button ng-click="foo()" class="submit">submit</button>
```

And the controller:

```
$scope.foo = function() {
    if ($scope.mbrscemployee == 'yes') {

    }
}
```

Comment: how we can give span order to be clicked automatically inside if(){}

Answer (score 0):

you can write ng-click="someFunction" on submit button which will check your variable $scope.mbrscemployee is true and then you can call subsequent function from there.!